# Defined Blogname Override?

Tags: customization

Is there a way to override the blogname such as `define("WP_BLOGNAME","My Blog");`

I've looked high and low and have found nothing. Testing it doesn't work either.

This is so I can help determine between dev and production environments easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The name comes from `get_option('blogname')`.

So you can filter it in a mu-plugin:

```
add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'local_blogname' );

function local_blogname( $name )
{
    return "✋ $name";
}
```